# Place img relatively to text responsively

Tags: html, css

I have h1 centered in div by
`text-align: center;
line-height: 150px;
vertical-align: top;`

And now I want to place img for example in left-top corner of the text. Ofc I want it not to move when the window is changing sizes. It has to always be at the corner of text.
I tried setting `position: absolute / fixed` to img and then manipulate with `top` and `left` percent values, but the img is changing position relatively to the text (h1) when I change window sizes.

I'm very new to CSS (also HTML) and I see I don't understand what is happening on the screen and don't have an idea how to solve this problem..

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
}
.logo {
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-image: url(../img/forest.jpeg);
  background-position: 30% 20%;
}
.logo h1 {
  font-family: Coiny-Regular;
  color: skyblue;
}
.logo img {
  position: fixed;
  height: 2.5em;
  top: 7%;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1> Example </h1>
    <img src="img/image.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the html part as well?

Comment: @HSharma - Sorry, already edited question

Comment: You are not closing this div <div class = "logo">>

Comment: Just copied incorrectly, already fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `img`:

- use `position: absolute`
- place it inside the `h1`

The `h1`:

- make it `display: inline-block;`
- have `position: relative` (will make the `img`'s absolute position relative to the `h1`)

The `display: inline-block;` on the `h1` will make its bounding box match its content and make it possible for the image's absolute position to stay at an exact place.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
}
.logo {
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-image: url(../img/forest.jpeg);
  background-position: 30% 20%;
}
.logo h1 {
  font-family: Coiny-Regular;
  color: skyblue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1> Example
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Works nice, thanks so much also for explanation. But the h1 is no longer in the center of div vertically :/

Comment: @Criss It has the same position as in your question, I didn't change any of that.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you have some sort of text centered inside your div and want a floating image on the top left corner of your text but you don't want the image to change positions inside the div when the position of the text changes.

```css
.test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.test img {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
.test h1 {
  padding-right: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <img src="http://www.techinsights.com/uploadedImages/Public_Website/Content_-_Primary/Teardowncom/Sample_Reports/sample-icon.png" height="40px" width="40px">
  <h1>Sample Text</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: Yea, on corner of text. In your example the icon is on corner of whole div.
And you misunderstood the part with changing postions. I want the image to be always on the corner of text. So I want it to change position along with the text.

Comment: My apologies I responded to the question before it was edited.

Comment: It would be my fault then, but I didn't edit the text (just minor code fixes). :P So you don't know the solution?